# Error installing rabbitmq on Mac using brew

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, homebrew

Receiving the following error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "rabbitmq"
```

Tried reinstalling brew and updating brew with no help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, [rabbitmq](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rabbitmq) is a valid formula name, and I can install it just fine. Can you [edit] to provide more info: `brew --version`, macOS version, error logs from `brew install -v rabbitmq`. What about other formula (`brew install wget`)?

Answer (score 1):

its because your brew installation has some problems. Just try to reset it to master branch by running following command

```
git -C $(brew --repository homebrew/core) checkout master
```

then run

```
brew update
```

after that you can run

```
brew install rabbitmq
```

and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Like @gino-mempin commented, you should be able to install by using `brew install rabbitmq`.

You can use `brew doctor` and `brew config` to verify if you have local brew setup issue.

With that being said, we failed to update rabbitmq to latest 3.8.5 (there are several failed attempts).